# macOS Two-factor authentication Apple ID limit

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, icloud, apple-id

From the Apple Support document, [Two-factor authentication for Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204915)

> Two-factor authentication is available to iCloud and iTunes users with at least one device that's using the latest iOS or macOS. Learn more.

I know that on iOS devices there is a limit on the number of Apple IDs that you can use for 2FA which is 3 or 5. Once it's reached you can't link more Apple IDs even if you sign out from a previous one.

1. Does macOS devices have similar limitations?
2. Can I **un-link** Apple ID from my iPhone to use a different one somehow?